# Node.js mssql error handling with wrong input

Tags: node.js, sql-server, exception, parameters

Somehow try catch or .catch(error) doesn't show the exception that occurs when you pass not_a_date param here. To find out where was the problem I had to remove try/catch and see server crash with that error.

```
try {
        const pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(secret_server).connect();
        const result = await pool.request()
            .input('dtWhenImRich', sql.DateTime, notADateValue)
            .execute('[dbo].[RobDaBank]')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    }
```

Console output is just "error: {}". Without try/catch it is "TypeError: parameter.value.getTime is not a function", that I ideally wanted to see as an error in the catch block.

Comment: Perhaps it depends on what `notADateValue` actually is? If, for example, I use `const notADateValue = 'Hello, world!'` then I'll catch an `EPARAM`, but if I use `const notADateValue = 1.0` then I'll catch an `ERROR: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.RobDaBank'.`